# PySpark Streaming + Kafka Word Count not printing any results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, word-count

This is my first interaction with Kafka and Spark Streaming and i am trying to run WordCount script given below. The script is pretty standard as given in many online blogs. But for whatever reason, spark streaming is not printing the word counts. It is not throwing any error, just does not display the counts. 
I have tested the topic via console consumer, and there messages are showing up correctly. I even tried to use foreachRDD to see the lines coming in and thats also not showing anything.

Thanks in advance!

Versions: kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2 , Spark2.2.1, spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.1

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaWordCount")
sc.setCheckpointDir('c:\Playground\spark\logs')
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
ssc.checkpoint('c:\Playground\spark\logs')

zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
print(str(zkQuorum))
print(str(topic))
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
print(kvs)

counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
                  .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                  .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
counts.pprint(num=10)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Producer Code:

```
import sys,os
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
import time

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092")
topic = "KafkaSparkWordCount"

def read_file(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        print('started reading...')
        contents = f.readlines()
        for content in contents:
            future = producer.send(topic,content.encode('utf-8'))
            try:
                future.get(timeout=10)
            except KafkaError as e:
                print(e)
                break
            print('.',end='',flush=True)
            time.sleep(0.2)

    print('done')       


if __name__== '__main__':
    read_file('C:\\\PlayGround\\spark\\BookText.txt')
```

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with your code. Data from server is not coming in a streaming fashion. Check Kafka Producer code.

Comment: Hi Mayank, thanks for the response. I have added the producer code as well above, please suggest what might be wrong here.

Comment: Is the data big enough to continue streaming for sometime. I think data is getting sent by kafka and gets over before spark accepts it. Can you check it? Can you see data being sent by this Kafka producer code? Meaning, print('done') should not be printed for a while.. otherwise there is no data left for spark to accept.

Comment: Checked it, the process takes atleast 5 minutes to get to the done statement. I made sure that spark part is initiated way before the producer is done.

Comment: Although not sure what createStream accepts, can you check once all arguments passed because everything else seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

how many cores do you use ?

Spark Streaming needs at least two cores, one for the  receiver and one for the processor.

Comment: I am using it on my local machine with default settings. My machine has 4 cores.